# Unity: Cannot load scene from asset bundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm having an issue with the new Asset Bundle system in Unity 5 Beta RC3. Now before i present my question, I've been working with this very project in Unity 5 since beta 17 (4 weeks ago), and everything worked perfectly fine loading several different scenes and all of their dependencies right up until i made a change yesterday that broke them.

So please, only answer this question if you are working with the new Unity 5 Asset Bundle system provided by Vincent Zhang on the unity forums. I will ask this question there as well.

So my project has 3 scenes, (loader.unity, title.unity, and rink.unity).
loader.unity is the only scene in the build settings, it is the first scene loaded. it has a single object in it that is marked for DontDestroyOnLoad. The loader object in that scene uses the LoadScenes script from the demo assets linked in this thread by Vincent Zhang http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/new-assetbundle-build-system-in-unity-5-0.293975/

It loads the second scene perfectly fine (title.unity) this scene just has a text field as a title for the project and a button to advance to the next scene.

when i press that button and load the third scene in the editor with "SimulateAssetBundles" turned on everything works just fine in the editor. and Everything worked fine up until yesterday as well.

Yesterday I got a new model from an artist for a new rink, i imported it into the scene and replaced a prototype i had built with ProBuilder since his was modeled in Maya and had perfectly accurate collision volumes and better materials.

This new model with new materials meant i had to adjust the lights in my scene, so I deleted the existing lights, and added 6 point lights similar to before, but different range and angle and intensity values.

Since there is high specularity on the ice material i wanted to see if i could add reflections, so i added reflection probes to the scene.

everything runs perfectly fine from the editor when i go from loader scene to title scene and play in rink scene and back to title scene. But when i do a build and it loads the rink scene i get this error in my logs and something strange happens.

```
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkscene
Couldn't open the cache file! URL: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkscene
```

I've checked that nothing is accessing the file on my filesystem maybe keeping it read/write locked. I've tried completely whiping my project and re-pulling from Git and even cloning into a completely different folder on my computer so its definitely not a problem with no being able to find/read the file.

I've tried it on a second computer and still have the same problem and the problem also occurs in Web Player Builds as well as standalone PC.

Reinstalling Unity, deleting my library and reimporting all my assets, clearing web cache all has no effect.

I'm assuming that something in the lighting changes or the reflections broke the scene and some part of those settings aren't properly in the assetbundle file.

here's the full output.log

---

```
Initialize engine version: 5.0.0f3 (b472b25463a4)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.0]
    Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (ID=0x416)
    Vendor:   Intel
    VRAM:     128 MB
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\ProBuilderCore.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\ProBuilderCore.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\ProBuilderMeshOps.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\ProBuilderMeshOps.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\ProCore.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\ProCore.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\SixBySeven.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\SixBySeven.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\Rewired_Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\Rewired_Core.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.105 seconds
<RI> Initializing input.

<RI> Input initialized.

desktop: 1920x1080 60Hz; virtual: 1920x1080 at 0,0
<RI> Initialized touch support.

Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\System.dll (this message is harmless)
Non platform assembly: data-0B85BE18 (this message is harmless)
Fallback handler could not load library D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/Mono/data-0B85BE18.dll
Non platform assembly: data-0B885558 (this message is harmless)
Fallback handler could not load library D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/Mono/data-0B885558.dll
Non platform assembly: data-03642020 (this message is harmless)
Fallback handler could not load library D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/Mono/data-03642020.dll
Platform assembly: D:\hockey\smashmouthhockey\SmashMouth\Smash Mouth Hockey_Data\Managed\System.Xml.dll (this message is harmless)
Setting up 2 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 201c -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 20c4 -> priority: 1 
Start to load scene title at frame 3

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/titlescene
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesbluetexture
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesredtexture
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/soundfxmixer
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/boardsmaterial
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/mastersoundmixer
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/musictrack
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/boardsmaterial cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/1097cfd4ed72da3c833837a364aff73b9685f325
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesredtexture cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/dd1c6272b74d4b2c0f47d33fef3686331939c865
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/soundfxmixer cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/aac390ad5c870bfebde44819a26978f95dd034bf
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesbluetexture cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/5a3378bf86a6696b99a45c23524352a09228e877
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/boardsmaterial
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesbluetexture
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesredtexture
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/soundfxmixer
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/mastersoundmixer cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/32feea768cb3a81dc240aaec25edbf1d176b9502
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/mastersoundmixer
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/helmetmodel
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/helmetmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/4d4e39f7bfde9e449b92064321b4581e6e13d746
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/helmetmodel
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rollerbladeanims
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/stickmodel
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/combatanims
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/stickmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/93e306bfd4a67fb7f59275f0ef276df822944e27
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/stickmodel
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesmodel
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/padsmodel
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/buttonanimcontrol
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/addbeb7117c66016716775b986706c079b509dec
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesmodel
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/playeranimcontroller
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinktexture
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/titlecanvasprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/padsmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/b9e610874b8d0bd811a06872d792cd3dcebb00c0
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/buttonanimcontrol cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/e0324af702d3031b16e5e8569a30e36ec6671aaa
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/padsmodel
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/buttonanimcontrol
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/pucksounds
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rollerbladeanims cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/954b581fe2c37dff73b4fc251425768612bd5397
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rollerbladeanims
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dripsound
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/playeranimcontroller cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/ff1adb035138678e27d833b785d8e1e0f33b42aa
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/playeranimcontroller
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/medievilanims
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinktexture cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/7ab4bde241704ad64d8cd0b8ad99b905974f7a26
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/combatanims cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/7f42a010b3a325a92add388dc2de788801d9fae7
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/titlecanvasprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/859d825c6a340837c1249938d21c7132566e2d41
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/combatanims
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinktexture
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/titlecanvasprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/pucksounds cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/142ed85232f6b8b4fd08213f25cba318f39b67e7
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dripsound cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/5f945753735525ce223720ddefe75d3a561aecdc
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/pucksounds
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dripsound
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/musictrack cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/ab96872c052b5288e6589b92bde7fdf69aeece86
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/musictrack
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/medievilanims cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/900bc7fbc395dc5eace11da6e6fd60fbba304b83
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/medievilanims
Finish loading scene title at frame 86

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

Start to load scene rink at frame 215

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkscene
Couldn't open the cache file! URL: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkscene

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

Finish loading scene rink at frame 220

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)

starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/869226af3d6fa5bc36a8cc606d67841f2c36d03b
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkprefab
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesprefab
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gamecontrollerprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/1262bff4d6099e1952a27eed38df005e2003236c
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/dimplesprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gamecontrollerprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/b31940b89ceeee4f88293d0e9246ab2fd62811fa
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gamecontrollerprefab
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/goalieprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/goalieprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/61940be90d34ba945bdd10fbf5c6af00d137d935
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/puckprefab
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/goalieprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/puckprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/f0e195062c79bfb26a33c2a94a39d60a0d7478b1
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/puckprefab
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/buzzersound
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/crowdambiencesound
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/buzzersound cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/2a20983a53f44fe1807785e3575956b641541375
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/buzzersound
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/crowdambiencesound cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/9aa09e7e8398377c8719f9ca72df4c80c44e074b
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/crowdambiencesound
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gamestatemachine
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gamestatemachine cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/a41bd379a771d910f82b100610731266915ceffc
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gamestatemachine
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/scoreboardsprite
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/nettexture
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netdiffusematerial
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/scoreboardsprite cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/76846fc0db206621e5792f5d3d243d9565e7d4c2
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/scoreboardsprite
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkmaterial
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/nettexture cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/d49863793336391b0b29759771560bf9a3a0d2b1
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/nettexture
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkcanvasprefab
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netdiffusematerial cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/e7ea9e826c3537fe905c373ef36f2b18d25fdbb6
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netdiffusematerial
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/skatingsounds
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkmaterial cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/23b5a4af0624f7f475f01bde74b673a90e50b153
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkmaterial
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkcanvasprefab cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/9336273dc329ea68bb860c1178962a50dedb0b67
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkcanvasprefab
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gruntsounds
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkmodel
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/skatingsounds cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/d5ed52c6dab1894d997dcb9aad382abd5ae63211
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/skatingsounds
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netmodel
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/a57966374290bfda73cec4df8dd308b1d498eefd
starting www download: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netcollisionmodel
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gruntsounds cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/b5a98fd354ed8b567b53f3c52968b57ed768d602
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/gruntsounds
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/rinkmodel
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/e900766a79666ec9e26293dc4d89f1100470a48a
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netmodel
file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netcollisionmodel cached to C:/Users/Brian/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/WebPlayer/Cache/DefaultCompany_Smash Mouth Hockey/9f04c5f1ab665e5d67e62a634f45c732f8118c33
loading from cache: file://D:/hockey/smashmouthhockey/SmashMouth/Smash Mouth Hockey_Data/StreamingAssets/AssetBundles/Windows/netcollisionmodel
```

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that Enlighten didn't like having objects marked as "Static" in the inspector. I'm assuming that the baked lighting data wasn't being included in the scene's asset bundle, thus causing an error when it loads.

I went into my scene, unchecked "Static" and rebuilt my asset bundles, and everything worked again.